# React-route and server-side rendering - how to render components with data

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

I've bean able to pass data to react components when rendered them at server-side like:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    var reactHtml = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(component({data}));
    res.render('index.jade', {reactOutput: reactHtml});
});
```

Now I've changet it to

server.js:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    // match the routes to the url
    match({ routes: routes, location: req.url }, (err, redirect, props) => {
        props.data = {q:123};
        const appHtml =  ReactDOMServer.renderToString(routerContext(props));
        res.render('index.jade', {reactOutput: appHtml});
    })
});
```

router context

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
    render: function(){return(<RouterContext {...this.props}  />)}
});
```

and routes

```
module.exports = (
    <Route path="/" component={App} {...this.props}>
        <IndexRoute component={List}/>
        <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
    </Route>
);
```

App.jsx

```
var App = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        console.log(this.props);
        return (
            <div id="app-root" className="container">
                <Nav/>
                <h1>{this.props.q}</h1>
                {this.props.children}
                <div className="Row">
                    <div className="footer col-lg-12"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

});
```

So for example I want do get data from this point `props.data = {q:123};` in my App component, but when I do `console.log(this.data);` in App component render method I've got history, location and etc, but not my data. Is there anyway to pass data `{q:123}` to component (App or List or About) props from server.js logic?

(Let's asume we always load some data for now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `props.data = {q:123};` doesn't get called anywhere, because RouterContext doesn't know what to do with it.

The three arguments to the callback function you pass to `match` are:

1. error: A javascript Error object if an error occured, `undefined` otherwise.
2. redirectLocation: A `Location` object if the route is a redirect,
   `undefined` otherwise
3. renderProps: The props you should pass to the routing context if the route matched, `undefined`
                      otherwise.

   If all three parameters are `undefined`, this means that there was no route found matching the
   given location.

To understand the mechanism you could add console.dir here

```
match({ routes: routes, location: req.url }, (err, redirect, props) => {
        console.dir(props);
        const appHtml =  ReactDOMServer.renderToString(routerContext(props));
        res.render('index.jade', {reactOutput: appHtml});
    })
});
```

And `console.dir(props.components)` would show you all the components that are being passed to render. You could also create a new react element here and push it to `props.components`

**To pass data into your app component** *with no stores*

Modify this function to have the ability to retrieve data, and create dummy component with the new data

routes.jsx

```
module.exports = function(serverData){
  var Dummy= React.createClass({
     render: function () {
       return (
         <div> customProps=serverData </div>
             );}
         });

  return(
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path='data' component={{PonyMan: Dummy}}
        <IndexRoute component={List}/>
        <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
    </Route>
   );
}
```

server.jsx:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    myCustomData = 'I like ponies'
    const routes = createRoutes(myCustomData); //from imported routes.jsx
    match({ routes: routes, location: req.url }, (err, redirect, props) => {
        const appHtml =  ReactDOMServer.renderToString(routerContext(props));
        res.render('index.jade', {reactOutput: appHtml});
    })
});
```

App.js

```
var App = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div id="app-root" className="container">
                <Nav/>
                <h1>{this.props.main}</h1>//this now shows <div>I Like Ponies</div>

                //this can still display other routes
                {this.props.children}
                <div className="Row">
                    <div className="footer col-lg-12"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }    
});
```

P.S. it would be way easier using redux stores 
check this project to see a good example of react-router redux express mongoose project with server side rendering 
https://github.com/choonkending/react-webpack-node

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've checked a demo. Looks like it does exactly what I need. I've to spend couple hours to read sources. Actualy I've read react-route source and find path to fork and  modify 'getChildContext' function in RouterContext to make it transfer additinonal data to child context. But your way looks more convinient

Comment: yea, I'd consider this more of a 'hack'. It's really easier to use something like redux stores for dynamic content. And if you want to make the initial server render you can add something like [this](https://github.com/choonkending/react-webpack-node/blob/master/app/api/fetchComponentDataBeforeRender.js) which resolves promises for your custom data before render, so you still get all the SEO pros

Answer (score 2):

You need to serialize your data and add it to the page on the server render, for example if you pass it to your root component as `initialState`:

```
renderInitialState() {
    const innerHtml = `window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(this.props.initialState)}`;
    return <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: innerHtml}} />;
}
```

So:

```
<script>window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = JSON.stringify(yourObject);</script>
```

Note that it looks like you're using jade to render the "shell" instead of React. So same thing applies but do it for the jade template.

You would typically render that at the bottom of your `<body>` (but above your app js script).

If you're using flux for your client state you would pass this object when creating your store, e.g. for redux:

```
const store = configureStore(window.__INITIAL_STATE__);
```

Comment: I've used jade as example what I did before react-route. I underestand your point, but looks like it will dismiss pros of server-sider rendering (seo friendly and etc), becouse included js have to be executed in browser. When I've use jade + react, I was rendering full page with data at server side. That what I try to do now with react-router (and without jade)

Comment: Actually, my bad - I've wrote wrong question name. So, change it now.

Comment: The idea is to render on the server, and then pass the data needed so that a second render can happen on the client that's the same. All isomorphic apps have to pass data/the store to the client still - see https://github.com/DominicTobias/universal-react/ for example